# how to auto fill html input using different html input

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<html>
<input name='name'>
<input name='handphone'>
</html>
```

I need some script to make if user type on name and their 'handphone' data that store on db will show on second input form

example if done

```
<form>
<input name='name' value='surya'>
<input name='handphone' value='081392111098'>
</form>
```

Comment: do you want it to automatically reflect or just saving the input in the database and then fetching the content and rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need that `if Any User type name input and if name is in database then headphone input autofill from database`. For this  You have to Use `ajax` or `jQuery`.

thanks

Comment: how that happen, I need some code to understand this solution, since I am not advanced in javascript

Comment: [Tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html)

This demonstrates the use of AJAX, PHP, Javascript and MySQL. Hope it helps.
It would be better if you post your your DB table to get the apt solution for your problem.
Hope it helps.

Comment: okay since it a credential data I think to used 'POST' sending data method to keep all process within php code